# How to make make dynamic title with no, single and multi selection of slicer values in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table named **Sheet1**. It has three columns, RadioFinalizedBy, ScanCompleteDate, and, RadioFinalisedDate. RadioFinalizedBy has names in it.

| RadioFinalizedBy | ScanCompleteDate | RadioFinalisedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 01-01-2024 | 02-02-2024 |
| bbb | 02-01-2024 | 03-02-2024 |
| ccc | 03-01-2024 | 04-02-2024 |
| ddd | 04-01-2024 | 04-02-2024 |

I want to make a dynamic title with RadioFinalizedBy in Slicer. The dynamic title should show 'Radio Finalized by' when selected nothing. It should show one name as 'Radio Finalized by [name]' when selecting one value and it should show multiple names separated by a comma when selecting multiple values.

Below is my take on this -

```
Dynamic Title = 
VAR SelectedValues = VALUES(Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy])
VAR SelectedCount = COUNTROWS(SelectedValues)
RETURN
    IF(
        SelectedCount = 0,
        "Radio Finalized by",
        IF(
            SelectedCount = 1,
            "Radio Finalized by " & SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy]),
            "Radio Finalized by " & CONCATENATEX(SelectedValues, Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy], ", ", Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy])
        )
    )
```

But with this measure when selecting nothing, all the values are displayed in the title.

Below is the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ISFILTERED(...)` to determine if it has been filtered.

```
Dynamic Title = 
  var selectedValues =
    CONCATENATEX(
      DISTINCT(Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy]),
      [RadioFinalizedBy],
      ", "
    )
  return
    IF(
      ISFILTERED(Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy]),
      "Radio Finalized by " & selectedValues,
      "Radio Finalized by"
    )
```

If you want to capture if all have been selected (which `ISFILTERED` will also return true) then you can have:

```
Dynamic Title = 
  var selectedValues =
    CONCATENATEX(
      DISTINCT(Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy]),
      [RadioFinalizedBy],
      ", "
    )
  var selectedCount = COUNTROWS( DISTINCT(Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy]) )
  var allCount = 
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS( DISTINCT(Sheet1[RadioFinalizedBy]) ),
      ALL(Sheet1)
    )
  return
    IF(
      selectedCount <> allCount,
      "Radio Finalized by " & selectedValues,
      "Radio Finalized by"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. With the second DAX code, if all the values are selected (all the slicer values are never selected in the real world), then no values are shown in the title.

Comment: As by its design and intention - ie if all selected is the same as none selected. Hence why I provided the two options, depending which you wanted.